# Findcontrol and client side object

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

1 - Is it possible to handle controls that generate dynamically via java script or other way in page ?

2- What is the mechanism of find control, if I have my `TextBox` in `UpdatePanel` ?

For Example how can i get value of controls(textBox) that  has been added to table :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "txtSabeghe_" + (i + 1) + "Col_" + (j + 1);
                cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            Table5.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Table And button of Function Both Are in Update Panel to Avoid Postback

Comment: How are you generating controls & which control ? What are the values that you want to access in your code ? where do you want to find that `TextBox` in JavaScript or in back end code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too general, but I'll do my best to answer based on what I "think" you're asking.

1. Yes, all .net controls render as HTML in the DOM so you can handle them exactly as you would a DOM element, except that .net renders DOM with extra stuff in the `id` attribute i.e. **ctl_001_** etc, so you need to use the `ClientID` property. You can of course set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` in the web.config [as this article shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), this will leave the IDs as you specify.

   ```
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="mytextbox" />
   ```

   And your script.

   ```
   // without ClientIDMode = 'Static'
   var element = document.getElementById('<%=mytextbox.ClientID%>');

   // with ClientIDMode = 'Static'
   var element = document.getElementById('mytextbox');
   ```
2. `Control.FindControl` is a server side method (of the `Control` base class) that takes the ID (as a string) of the control you want to find, which can be used as follows.

   ```
   <asp:Panel runat="server" id="mypanel">
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="mytextbox" />
   </asp:Panel>
   ```

   And in your code behind.

   ```
   TextBox tbx = mypanel.FindControl("mytextbox");
   ```

**EDIT - Finding a control using master pages**

If you want to find your control using master pages, you're best filtering through the parents like so.

```
// parent place holder in master page
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderID");

// parent panel in content place holder
UpdatePanel pnl = cph.FindControl("UpdatePanelID");

// child of parent that you're interested in
TextBox tbx = pnl.FindControl("TextBoxID");
```

Comment: +1 for great Explanation . `<input id="ctl00_Main_txtSabeghe_1Col_1" type="text" name="ctl00$Main$txtSabeghe_1Col_1">` is rendered cod of text box ! i should use `name` attr or id for `FindControl` in my code

Comment: @Moslem7026 you can use the ID of the element with `.ClientID` see the script in part 1 of my answer.

Comment: and how about using of findcontrol if my text box is in row of table ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 it depends on how you're creating your update panel. If dynamically then you have no specific reference to it, and so you must **find** it with `FindControl`. In these instances you must iterate through the hierarchy: `ContentPlaceHolder.FindControl(ParentContainer).FindControl(Child)`

Comment: if i have a text box in row[0]col[0] of a table that placed in  `Table tb = (Table)this.Master.FindControl("Main").FindControl("UpdatePanel1").FindControl("DynamicTable").FindControl("Table5");`       i should access to textbox through this code?
        `TextBox tb = (TextBox)tb.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("txtID");` Or i dont need ro describe rows and cols of table ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 you have your reference to your `ContentPlaceHolder` parent, so you can just find the `TextBox` within that using `TextBox tbx = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("Main").FindControl("txtID")`.